# PHP editing data from the database

Tags: php, mysql

i am trying to edit database before updating.first i am trying to edit the database using echo after that i want to update desired fields in the same table.please find my code below....
 please help...i need to fetch values from database patient and need to update in the same table....

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>

    <head>
        <title>Form Edit Data</title>
    </head>

    <body>
        <table border=1>
            <tr>
                <td align=center>MODIFY PATIENT DATA</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <table>
                        <? include "db.php";//database connection $pid=$_POST[ 'pid']; $name=$_POST[
                        'name']; $age=$_POST[ 'age']; $sex=$_POST[ 'sex']; $mobileno=$_POST[
                        'mobileno']; $vaccine=$_POST[ 'vaccine']; $diagno=$_POST[ 'diagno']; $fee=$_POST[
                        'fee']; $order=s printf( "SELECT * FROM `hms`.`patient` WHERE pid='%s'", mysql_real_escape_string($pid));
                        $result=m ysql_query($order); if (!$result) die( 'Error: (' . mysql_errno()
                        . ') ' . mysql_error()); $row=m ysql_fetch_assoc($result); ?>
                        <form method="post" action="update1.php">
                            <table style=" border:5px solid silver" cellpadding="10px" cellspacing="10px"
                            align="center" border="0">
                                <tr>
                                    <td colspan="4" style="background:#0066FF; color:#FFFFFF; fontsize:20px">PATIENT DETAILS</td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <td>Patient Name</td>
                                    <td>
                                        <input type="text" name="name" size="20" value=<?php echo $row[ 'name'];
                                        ?>
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <td>Patient ID</td>
                                    <td>
                                        <input type="text" name="pid" size="20" value=<?php echo $row[ 'pid'];
                                        ?>
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <td>Age</td>
                                    <td>
                                        <input type="text" name="age" size="10" value=<?php echo $row[ 'age'];
                                        ?>
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <td>Sex</td>
                                    <td>
                                        <input type="text" name="sex" size="20" value=<?php echo $row[ 'sex'];
                                        ?>?>">
                                        <tr>
                                            <td>Mobile No.</td>
                                            <td>
                                                <input type="text" name="mobileno" size="20" value=<?php echo $row[
                                                'mobileno']; ?>
                                            </td>
                                        </tr>
                                        <tr>
                                            <td>Diagnosis</td>
                                            <td>
                                                <input type="text" name="diagno" size="40" value=<?php echo $row[
                                                'diagno']; ?>
                                            </td>
                                        </tr>
                                        <tr>
                                            <td>Vaccine</td>
                                            <td>
                                                <input type="text" name="vaccine" size="20" value=<?php echo $row[
                                                'vaccine']; ?>
                                            </td>
                                        </tr>
                                        <tr>
                                            <td>Fee Received</td>
                                            <td>
                                                <input type="text" name="fee" size="20" value=<?php echo $row[ 'fee'];
                                                ?>
                                                <tr>
                                                    <td align="right">
                                                        <input type="submit" name="submit value" value="UPDATE">
                                                    </td>
                                                </tr>
                        </form>
                        </table>
                        </td>
                        </tr>
                    </table>
    </body>

</html>
```

My table is showing values like this:

```
Patient Name <? echo   ">
Patient ID   <? echo   ">
.
.
.
.
Fee Received <? echo    ">
```

It is displaying `<? echo   ">` I tried to use `<?php echo  ">` but giving error ....

Comment: *sidenote:* stop using deprecated `mysql_*` functions. use MySQLi or PDO instead.

Comment: What is your question? The last part is not valid PHP codes.

Comment: @tepkenvannkorn I was thinking of making that edit, but OP is providing line numbers with his error messages, and the changes you made to the layout have made it so those line numbers no longer line up with the appropriate lines in his code.

Comment: you did'nt closed the input tags. and incorrect the open and close php tags.

Answer (score 2):

Change all instances of things like this:

```
<? echo "$row[age]"?>
```

to this:

```
<?=$row['age']?>
```

`<?=(whatever)?>` is shorthand for a php echo command, and the other change I made was to remove the quotes from around the `$row[age]` variable, and put `age` in quotes. This is because `age` is referring to the name of a db row column, rather than a PHP constant, so it must be in quotes in order to work properly. The same changes must be made to all other similar db column calls.

EDIT: Since it seems your server has short tags disabled, rather than using the short echo (`<?=$val?>`), you need to use `<?php echo $val ?>` **AND** change every instance of `<?` to `<?php`. I believe what's happening is the db code isn't executing, which means your `$row` variable is never getting instantiated for echoing to the user.

Also, as others have pointed out, the `mysql_*` functions are deprecated and no longer supported. You should switch to `mysqli_*` functions or a PDO, to make sure your code doesn't stop working due to a php software update.

Comment: Thanks for quick response.<input type="text" name="name"
        size="20" value="<?=$row['name']?>"> i change my echo like this...Patient Name: <?=$row['name']?> it is displaying like this...

Comment: What's the extension on the file you're using to display the form? It needs to be .php. If it is .php, try replacing `<?=` with `<?php echo` - so `<input [...] value="<?php echo $row['name'] ?>">`

Comment: It is showing error Patient Name <br /><font size='1'><table class='xdebug-error' dir='ltr' border='1' cellspacing='0' cellpadding='1'><tr><th align='left' bgcolor='#f57900' colspan= ( ! ) Notice: Undefined variable: row in ....\edit1.php on line 41..

Comment: I think I know what's going on: your server has short tags turned off, so the call you're making to the database isn't executing. In addition to changing the short echo (`<?=`) to `<?php echo`, make sure every instance of `<?` is changed to `<?php`.

Comment: @HiHello You didn't change the first `<?` (line 15) to `<?php`. Do that, and I think it will work.

Comment: after changing to <?php on line no. 15 ...error is undefined index name,pid...fee on line no, 18,19,20...25

Comment: That's because you're calling on `$_POST` variables that haven't been set. For each of those lines change it to `$age = (isset($_POST['age'])?$_POST['age']:'');`. This is a ternary statement that will first check for the existence of `$_POST['age']` and then only assign that to `$age` if it exists, otherwise it will assign a blank string

Comment: @DiMono then it will fail because the id is empty and it will result in nothing from the mysql query. Wish you gl with this I am out, he needs to read more of the PHP manual.

Comment: @Prix One issue at a time; the code will succeed with no results, and then he has to add `?pid=somevalidnumber` to the url

Comment: @DiMono or use another page to post the data and only accept if the data is not empty ;)

Comment: @HiHello Also worth noting: there are a lot of unclosed html tags in the posted code, including the `<input>` tags on lines 65/66, 72/73, 79/80, and 86. Those open tags are very likely to cause problems, so you should make sure to go through your code and close every tag that's not already been closed.

Comment: thanks for the posts.. now errors were ressolved.. as you said i am checking the tags..